# MySQL - Find intersection of values in a column

Tags: mysql, intersection

I have a table which consists of columns **pid** and **numbers** separated by comma.

Sample:

```
pid numbers
1    1,2,5
2    2,3
3    3,4
```

I want to find whether all the **pid** columns are 'connected' to each other or not.

Example : pid 1 is connected to pid 2 linked by number 2 and similarly pid 2 is connected to pid 3 by number 3, so pid 1, 2, 3 are connected to each other.

Comment: _I want to find..._ What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using 'match against' and 'like' operators but that was manual processing. I'm looking for something which is sort of more automated.

Comment: if you use a normalized database schema you can do it easily. No items separated by commas but single rows for each number. Can you modify the schema?

Comment: Please post your query which you have tried till now.

Comment: "and numbers separated by comma" In other words, you DON'T have a database. I'd be tempted to take a look at nested sets for this particular problem.

Comment: @adi Till now, I have only tried seraching manually like `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE gid = 0 AND MATCH(number) AGAINST('some number' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: @Strawberry the numbers are stored in column of type varchar in MySQL
And can you explain further about the solution using nested sets?

Comment: @Lelio Yes. I can modify it for time being. Please provide an apt solution for a normalized database.